# Intermediate step(s) between manual prod and CI/CD for Node/Next on EC2

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, next.js, dev-to-production

For about 18 months now I've been working in Node; and for the last 6 months I've been slowly migrating my existing WordPress websites to NextJS.

To date, I've been deploying to production manually. I log into my production server, checkout the latest release from GitHub, build, and do a pm2 restart.

Even though the above workflow seems to be the most commonly documented around the internet, it's always felt a little wrong to me.

Recently, I found myself in a situation where I needed to customise some 3rd party code. So, my main code now has a line in `package.json` that says

```
{
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "react-share": "file:../react-share/react-share-4.4.1.tgz",
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

which implies that I'm going to checkout my custom react-share, build it somewhere on the production server, change this line to point to wherever I put it, and then rebuild.

Also, I'm using Prisma, which means that every time I deploy, before I do a build, I need to do an `npx prisma generate` to create the client.

This now all seems really, really wrong.

I don't know how a "simple" CI/CD environment might look, but whatever it looks like, it feels like overkill. It's just me doing development, and my production environment is a single EC2 server sitting behind AWS CloudFront.

It seems to me that I should be doing something more/different than what I'm currently doing, in service to someday moving to a CI/CD model, if/when I have a whole team working on this, or sufficient users that I have multiple load-balanced servers and need production to be continually up.

In particular, it feels like I shouldn't be building on the production server.

Are there any intermediary step(s) I can/should be taking for faster/less-error-prone/less-down-time deployment to a single EC2 instance for Next/Node apps, between manually deploying as I am currently, and some sort of CI/CD setup? Or are my only choices to do what I'm doing now, or go research how to do CI/CD?

Answer (score 2):

You're approaching towards your initial stages of what technically is called **DevOps**, if not already as it appears from your context. What you're asking is a broad topic, which is an understatement, and explaining each and everything here will almost be like writing an article about it, at the very least.

However, I'll brief you overall on how to approach with this.

> I don't know how a "simple" CI/CD environment might look, but whatever it looks like, it feels like overkill.

Simplicity & complexity are relative terms. A system which is complicated for one might be simple for another. CI/CD doesn't define any laws that you need to follow in order to create a perfect deployment procedure, as everyone's deployment requirement is unique (at some point).

If I mention it in bullet points, what you need to figure out before you start with setting up CI&CD, is -

- The sequence of steps your deployment procedure needs in order to deploy your latest version. As you have stated already that you've been doing deployment manually, that means you already know your steps. All you need to do is to fine-tune each step so that it shouldn't require manual intervention while being executed automatically by the CI program.
- Choose a CI program, like Travis CI, Circle CI, or if you're using GitHub, it has it's own GitHub Actions for the purpose, you can read their documentation for more details. Your CI program will be responsible for executing your deployment steps which you'll mention to it in whichever format it understands (mostly `.yml`).
- The CI program will execute your steps on behalf of you based on the condition which you'll provide, (like when code is pushed on prod branch). It will execute the commands on a machine (like your EC2), specifically, GitHub actions runner will be responsible for running your commands on your machine, the runner should be setup beforehand in the instance you intend to deploy your code on. More details on runners can be found in relevant documentations.
- Since the runner will actually execute the commands on your machine, make sure that all required commands and parameters, including the concerned files & directories are accessible to the runner program, from permissions point of view at least. For example, running your `npx prisma generate` command should require that `npx` command is available and executable in the system, and the concerned folders in which the command will CRUD files is accessible by the runner program. Similarly for all other commands.
- Get your hands on bash scripting as well.
- If your steps contain dynamic info, like the one you mentioned that in your `package.json` an npm script needs to be updated, then a custom bash script created to update the same automatically will help, for instance. There will be however, several other ways depending on the specific nature of the dynamic changes.

The above points are huge (by huge, I mean astronomically huge) oversimplification of the ways through which CI&CD pipelines are setup. But I hope you get the idea of it at least.

> In particular, it feels like I shouldn't be building on the production server.

Your feeling is legitimate. You should replicate your production environment (including deployment procedures) into a separate development environment as close as possible, in order to have all your experiments, development and testing done separately from production environment, and after successful evaluation on the development environment, deploy on production one. Steps like building will most likely be done on both environments, as it is something your program needs to run, irrespective of the environment it is running in. Your future team will appreciate this separation of environments.

> if/when I have a whole team working on this, or sufficient users that I have multiple load-balanced servers and need production to be continually up.

Again, this small statement in itself is a proper domain of IT department, known as **System Design**, in which, to put it simply, you or your team will create an architecture for your whole system which will support your business requirements and scaling as your audience increases, which is something a simple Stackoverflow QnA won't suffice to explain.

Therefore,

> or go research how to do CI/CD?

is what I'd recommend and you should also feel is the right way ahead, after reading everything above.

Useful references to begin with (not endorsing any resources, you can search for relevant/better resources too)

- [GitHub Actions self-hosted runners](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/hosting-your-own-runners/about-self-hosted-runners)
- [System Design - Getting started](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/getting-started-with-system-design/)
- [Bash scripting](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/shell-scripting-crash-course-how-to-write-bash-scripts-in-linux/)
- [Development, Staging, Production](https://dev.to/flippedcoding/difference-between-development-stage-and-production-d0p)